# Understanding Scala Notation syntax

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
abstract class AList {
  def head:Int
  def tail:AList
  def isEmpty:Boolean
  def ::(n: Int): AList = SimpleList(n, Empty)
}

object Empty extends AList {

  def head = throw new Exception("Undefined")

  def tail = throw new Exception("Undefined")

  def isEmpty = true

}

case class SimpleList(head: Int, tail: AList = Empty) extends AList {

  def isEmpty = false

}

1 :: 2 :: Empty
```

I wonder how the last line actually works. There is no implicit conversion from Int to SimpleList. Hence I do not understand the method call mechanism.

> Object.method(Arg)

I do not see that pattern here. I think a clarification of Scala notation (infix, suffix, postfix, etc...) would help. I'd like to understand the syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`::` is a method of the right operand. In scala if a method name ends in a colon the method is invoked on the right operand.
So `1 :: 2 :: Empty` is actually `Empty.::(2)` which returns a `SimpleList`.

The subsequent `1 :: <the-new-simple-list>` is easy to follow once you understand that `::` is a method of the right operand.

Answer (score 9):

In Scala, method names ending with a colon..

- form right-associative expressions
- are additionaly invokend on the right operand.

So `1 :: 2 :: Empty` is actually `Empty.::(2).::(1)`. .

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Invocation of the method on the right operand alone is not sufficient without right associativity.